# Convert camelCase function name to snake_case

Tags: python, algorithm, strings

I have the following code:

```
# tests/examples
cases = [
    ["getMyID", "get_my_id"],
    ["getMyAlphabetABC", "get_my_alphabet_abc"],
    ["getAlphabet", "get_alphabet"],
    ["simple", "simple"],
    ["getALetter", "get_a_letter"],
    ["getBook1", "get_book1"],
    ["simpleButNotSoSimpleBecauseItIsVeryLong", "simple_but_not_so_simple_because_it_is_very_long"]
    ]


def camel_case_to_underscore(t):
    start = 0
    parts = []
    for idx, c in enumerate(t):
        if c.isupper():
            parts.append(t[start:idx].lower())
            start = idx
    parts.append(t[start:].lower())
    for i in reversed([idx for idx, (i, j) in enumerate(zip(parts, parts[1:])) if len(i) == len(j) == 1]):
        parts[i] = parts[i] + parts.pop(i + 1)
    return "_".join(parts)


for p in cases:
    print(camel_case_to_underscore(p[0]), camel_case_to_underscore(p[0]) == p[1])  # should be True for all
```

It seems quite clunky, but works. Is there a way that this can be optimised **without using RegEx**. I feel like it can be done in only one `for` loop but I have had zero luck finding this method.

**EDIT**
Small improvement (I think it's actually worse performer) but it feels closer to me.

```
def camel_case_to_underscore(t):
    upper_idxs = [0] + [idx for idx, c in enumerate(t) if c.isupper()] + [len(t) + 1]
    parts = [t[start:end].lower() for start, end in zip(upper_idxs[:-1], upper_idxs[1:])]
    for i in reversed([idx for idx, (i, j) in enumerate(zip(parts, parts[1:])) if len(i) == len(j) == 1]):
        parts[i] = parts[i] + parts.pop(i + 1)
    return "_".join(parts)
```

Comment: Lacking a specification (as well as an example), what's to happen with `'Dog'`?

Comment: (What's the rule for `["getALetter", "get_a_letter"]`?)

Comment: (`camel_case_to_snake('anSQLquery')`)

Comment: Can you explain why you can't use the `re` library?  It's a standard part of Python (one of the "included batteries", if you like).

Comment: @greybeard should be `dog`, will add to the Q and for `getALetter`, there are three word `get` `a` and `letter` hence the result. It should be that not `get_aletter` for example as they are seperate.

Comment: @TobySpeight I am doing this as interview prep and in an interview I would never be able to think up a RegEx. Perhaps the optimal solution is RegEx (although matching all these scenarios will be difficult), it's just not in my use case.

Comment: Fair enough - though it may be a good idea to (separately) improve your regular expression skills, as interviewers may ask regex-related questions regardless of what you have practised!

Comment: `for getALetter, there are three [words]` How do I tell without a dictionary?

Comment: since `t` is lower case it's part of the first, `A` is upper case so must be a new word, same with `L` - reason it's not more is because `e` is lower case.

Answer (score 1):

On top of the other great answer, I'd like to review the extreme list comprehension you've used:

```
for i in reversed([idx for idx, (i, j) in enumerate(zip(parts, parts[1:])) if len(i) == len(j) == 1]):
    parts[i] = parts[i] + parts.pop(i + 1)
```

List comprehensions can be a great tool to express things in a usually more concise and sometimes clearer way. In our case, we are definitly in the "more concise part" but I think it is very hard to understand.

Reorganising things slightly may help:

```
for idx, (i, j) in reversed(list(enumerate(zip(parts, parts[1:])))):
    if len(i) == len(j) == 1:
        parts[idx] += parts.pop(idx + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's good that the code is tested.  We can improve that by incorporating the tests into the documentation:

```
def camel_case_to_underscore(t):
    '''Convert the supplied name to snake_case.

    Examples:
    >>> camel_case_to_underscore('getMyID')
    'get_my_id'
    >>> camel_case_to_underscore('getMyAlphabetABC')
    'get_my_alphabet_abc'
    >>> camel_case_to_underscore('getAlphabet')
    'get_alphabet'
    >>> camel_case_to_underscore('simple')
    'simple'
    >>> camel_case_to_underscore('getALetter')
    'get_a_letter'
    >>> camel_case_to_underscore('getBook1')
    'get_book1'
    >>> camel_case_to_underscore('simpleButNotSoSimpleBecauseItIsVeryLong')
    'simple_but_not_so_simple_because_it_is_very_long'
    '''
```

We can then run them (when file is executed as main, but not when loaded as a module):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    exit(doctest.testmod()[0] > 0)
```

---

We should add some more test cases, including PascalCase and words with initialisms at beginning and middle, not just the end:

```
    >>> camel_case_to_underscore('AccessHTTPServer')
    'access_http_server'
    >>> camel_case_to_underscore('IDForName')
    'id_for_name'
```

These ones fail (with more useful message, and non-zero exit status):

```
**********************************************************************
File "/home/tms/stackexchange/review/./281284.py", line 20, in __main__.camel_case_to_underscore
Failed example:
    camel_case_to_underscore('AccessHTTPServer')
Expected:
    'access_http_server'
Got:
    '_access_http_server'
**********************************************************************
File "/home/tms/stackexchange/review/./281284.py", line 22, in __main__.camel_case_to_underscore
Failed example:
    camel_case_to_underscore('IDForName')
Expected:
    'id_for_name'
Got:
    '_id_for_name'
**********************************************************************
1 items had failures:
   2 of   9 in __main__.camel_case_to_underscore
***Test Failed*** 2 failures.
```

That's something that could be improved.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look but in fairness, `AccessHTTPServer` is not camel case if I am correct as that's pascal case, I would assume `accessHTTPServer` gives the intended result.

Comment: Yes, if PascalCase is explicitly not converted, then the modified test passes.  It might be better to do something different if PascalCase input is detected - return it unchanged, or throw an exception, perhaps?

Comment: To be fair, making it PascalCase is pretty easy, don't explicity add 0 at the start of the list, only add it if it's not there, but beyond the scope of the question imo. I would rather a really good one that works with camelCase before I think about handling PascalCase.

Answer (score 0):

Iterating the string once seems a laudable goal.

"*The rule about two capital letters followed by a lower case one*" needs an annoying amount of state.

```
def to_snake_case(name):
    """ Convert a name to snake case:
    
        Assume a capital letter to start a new word
        to be preceded by an underscore unless at start of name
        or inside a run of capital letters. 
        If such a run is followed by a lowercase letter, it is again
        the start of a word.
        A "run" of one capital is converted to lower.
    """ 
    if not name:
        return name
    if (len(name) <= 1):
        return name.lower()
    # to avoid prepending an underscore before a Pascal case name
    result = name[0].lower() if name[1].islower() else name[0]
    previous = name[1]
    current = ""
    for current in name[2:]:
        if current.islower() and previous.isupper():
            if '_' != result[-1]:
                if len(result) < 2 or result[-2] == '_':  # backpatching?!
                    result = result[:-1] + result[-1].lower()
                result += '_'
            result += previous.lower()
        elif current.isupper() and previous.islower():
            result += previous + '_'
        else:
            result += previous
        previous = current     # alternatives including zip & pairwise
    return result + (current if '_' != result[-1] else current.lower())
```

Comment: That's a nice solution albeit confusing. I will try and get my head round and do some comparisons to my solution. I think you want to call a `.lower()` on the whole of the last line to meet the test cases exactly as I described.

Comment: I'm confused for the need of the backpatching line. I get what the line actually does but I'm not sure when that if statement would be true? Could you clarify for me please?

Comment: The "backpatching" kicks in with multiple capitals in a row (acronym/initialism) followed by (another capital and) a lower case letter